Problem with CSS Order in Nuxt 3: Server-side and Client-side Styles Are Loaded in Different Order
I'm working with Nuxt 3 and facing an issue with how stylesheets are loaded during SSR. Specifically, I’ve noticed that the order of stylesheets is different when rendered on the server and client, which causes layout issues.
Here’s a simplified example:
<template>
  <div>
    <Comp2 />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import Comp2 from './src/test/comp2.vue';
</script>

<template>
  <Comp1 :class="$style.Comp2"></Comp1>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import Comp1 from './comp1.vue';
</script>

<style module lang="scss">
.Comp2 {
  padding: 60px;
  border: 4px solid black;
}
</style>

<template>
  <div :class="$style.Comp1"></div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
</script>

<style module lang="scss">
.Comp1 {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>

When the page is rendered on the server (SSR), the order of stylesheets in the  looks like this:
[ 
  '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_nuxt/src/test/comp2.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang.module.scss" crossorigin>',
  '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_nuxt/src/test/comp1.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang.module.scss" crossorigin>' 
]

However, on the client side, the order is reversed:
[
  '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_nuxt/src/test/comp1.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang.module.scss" crossorigin>',
  '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_nuxt/src/test/comp2.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang.module.scss" crossorigin>' 
]

What I’ve tried:
Increasing the specificity of the selectors by using Comp2.Comp2 {} in the styles, that solve the issue of the different order
Using nitro.hooks.hook('render:html') to try to modify the order of the stylesheets on the server side.
But I'm unsure if there's a cleaner or more reliable way to handle this.
What I want to achieve:
I want to ensure that the order of stylesheets is the same on both the server and client to avoid any layout issues.

Can you please try the css import in Nuxt Config fie? Docs link:  https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/styling#the-css-property

unfortunately this is not suitable, you cannot specify this for each component, it is more likely for global styles
